# How to Merge two views in one view with Asp.net MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I added a new Controller then I selected the following **options:**

- **Template:** MVC Controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework.
- **Model class:** Movie (MvcMovie.Models).
- **Data context class:** MovieDBContext (MvcMovie.Models).
- **Views: Razor (CSHTML)**.

I got a folder of views which includes by default: Index, Creat, Edit, Detailes, and Delete.

**Everything is working fine to here.**

My problem that I'm trying to merge the codes of Create view with the codes of Index view(Two views in one).

The Error which i get:

**Compiler Error Message: CS1061:** 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Title' and no extension method 'Title' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my Merged View (Index.cshtml):

```
@model IEnumerable<ReMvc.Models.Movie>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Movie</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Genre)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
    </fieldset>
    }

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
 <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
    </td>
 </tr>
}

</table>
```

Here is my controller:
I renamed 'Create' ActionResult to Index

```
namespace ReMvc.Controllers
{
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    private MovieDbContext db = new MovieDbContext();

    //
    // GET: /Movies/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Movies.ToList());
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Movie movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Movies.Add(movie);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(movie);
    }
}
```

And here is my Model:
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;

```
namespace ReMvc.Models
{
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class MovieDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
}
```

I'm beginner with MVC and i stuck here for more than 4 days..
please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well to start your `model` is a type of `IEnumerable<ReMvc.Models.Movie>`.

So it's complaining that `IEnumerable<T>` does not have a method or property called `Title`:

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
```

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Title' and no extension method 'Title' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found

If you didn't mean to use an `IEnumerable<T>` for the Model so change it to:

```
@model ReMvc.Models.Movie
```

If you did mean to use a type of `IEnumerable<T>` then you will need to loop over your items to access them:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@foreach(var movie in Model)
{
<fieldset>
    <legend>Movie</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label(movie.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Editor(movie.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessage(movie.Title)
    </div>
}
```

I would also recommend that you do not have the data access in your presentation layer (your controller). Look at separating out your data access from your UI.

If you want to use a type of `IEnumerable<T>` and a type of `ReMvc.Models.Movie` in the same view? You will have to do something similar to the following.

You could create a new type and use this:

```
public class MovieViewModel()
{
    public ReMvc.Models.Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ReMvc.Models.Movie> MovieCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can pass that into your view

```
@model MovieViewModel
```

In your controller you just do this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MovieViewModel() 
    {
        MovieCollection = db.Movies.ToList(),
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Movie movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Movies.Add(movie);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    var model = new MovieViewModel()
    {
        Movie = movie,
    };
    return View(movie);
}
```

The downside to this is in your view you will now need to check if one is null (Because with your code, one property will always be null either `Movie` or `MovieCollection`). I would recommend splitting out your views and use a different Action Method name e.g. Details.

Comment: ,Yes i wanna use a type of IEnumerable<T> and a type of ReMvc.Models.Movie in the same view so i did as u mentioned..Added new type, passed it, and edited my controller.. and i get
Parser Error Message: Unexpected "foreach" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "foreach" with "@". And when i remove "@".I get 
Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ReMvc.ViewModel.MovieViewModel' because 'ReMvc.ViewModel.MovieViewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: I want you to see my view after editing but i couldn't post it in a comment !

Comment: Workssss! now without errors but foreach doesn't return any list to the Index view it seems that MovieCollection is empty!!!!
how to handel that, please?
here is Index.cshtml file
 [link](http://wikisend.com/download/554262/Index.cshtml)

Comment: If you are populating your `Movie.MovieCollection` like in my example and in your Database you have data, then it will be populated when it hits the view.

Comment: ,Not to nag but how populating my Movie.MovieCollection and Yes i have 4 rows in my Database

Comment: In your `Index()` action if you are using my example `    var model = new MovieViewModel()  { MovieCollection = db.Movies.ToList(),  };` then it will be populated by calling `db.Movies.ToList()`

Comment: Yes I'm using it !! but i'm afraid it because of foreach code here it's:
  ' foreach (var item in Model.MovieCollection) { <tr> <h1>Works</h1> <td> @Html.Display(item.Title) </td> <td> @Html.Display(item.ReleaseDate.ToString()) </td> <td> @Html.Display(item.Genre) </td> <td> @Html.Display(item.Price.ToString()) </td>        </tr> }'

Comment: @Ayman Could you please post a new question regarding this. I've answered how you can do it. But this seems to be getting quite cluttered now and this is possibly a different issue.

Comment: How to make a new question regarding to a previous question??.. i was digging google to do so but not even a clue! .. actually i'm new here !

Comment: That's fine. Just press the `Ask a question` button up the top right and post your new problem. Including your controller and view.

Comment: Finally, after many issues .. here it's 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990934/i-have-mixed-create-view-and-index-view-codes-in-one-view-so-how-to-retrieve-d
besides i couldn't come out with a clear question!