# I have mixed Create view and index view codes in one view. So, How to retrieve data from a database by that view in asp.net MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have merged two views in one view(one to create and the other one to display).So the new view will be able to add and retrieve data in the same time.
but it was only able to create a new row in the database without retrieve anything. There is 4 rows in the database.

here is my new view (Index): i added h1> Works/h1> to make sure foreach works

**Index.cshtml**

```
    @model ReMvc.ViewModel.MovieViewModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Movie</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(movie => movie.Movie.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(movie => movie.Movie.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(movie => movie.Movie.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(movie => movie.Movie.ReleaseDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(movie => movie.Movie.ReleaseDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(movie => movie.Movie.ReleaseDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(movie => movie.Movie.Genre)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(movie => movie.Movie.Genre)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(movie => movie.Movie.Genre)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(movie => movie.Movie.Price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(movie => movie.Movie.Price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(movie => movie.Movie.Price)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />

        </p>
    </fieldset>
       foreach (var item in Model.MovieCollection)
        {
            <tr>
                <h1>Works</h1>
                <td>
                    @Html.Display(item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Display(item.ReleaseDate.ToString())
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Display(item.Genre)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Display(item.Price.ToString())
                </td>
            </tr>
    }

    }
    <p>
        </p>
    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

My problem that from the above code foreach doesn't retrieve data from MovieCollection to index page.
Here is my model (Movie):

```
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    namespace ReMvc.Models
    {
        public class Movie
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
            public string Genre { get; set; }
            public decimal Price { get; set; }
        }

        public class MovieDbContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

And here is a new type to solve an issue:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

 namespace ReMvc.ViewModel
 {
    public class MovieViewModel
    {
        public ReMvc.Models.Movie  Movie  { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ReMvc.Models.Movie>  MovieCollection { get; set;      }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Data.Entity;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Mvc;
  using ReMvc.Models;
  using ReMvc.ViewModel;

 namespace ReMvc.Controllers
 {
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        private MovieDbContext db = new MovieDbContext();
        //
        // GET: /Movies/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var model = new MovieViewModel()
            { MovieCollection = db.Movies.ToList(), };
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Movies/Index

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Movie movie)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Movies.Add(movie);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            var model = new MovieViewModel()
            {
                Movie = movie,
            };
            return View(movie);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you add the exact problem into your question by pressing `Edit` please.

Comment: @Jamie Done. after the view code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. add the Enumerable list of row to use it with foreach, in the model in the entity folder:**

```
public partial class UserProfile
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string PostContent { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<workingOnAddPost.Entity.UserProfile> UserProfilesCollection { get; set; }
```

**2. edit the home controller, to make it deal with httpPost and httpGet requests**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private AddingPostEntities db = new AddingPostEntities();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        //return View( db.UserProfiles.ToList());


        var model = new UserProfile() 
        {
            UserProfilesCollection = db.UserProfiles.ToList(), 
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UserProfile userprofile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.UserProfiles.Add(userprofile);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(userprofile);
    }
       //
    // POST: /PostManager/Create
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

    // GET: /PostManager/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        UserProfile userprofile = db.UserProfiles.Find(id);
        if (userprofile == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(userprofile);
    }


    //
    // GET: /PostManager/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        UserProfile userprofile = db.UserProfiles.Find(id);
        if (userprofile == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(userprofile);
    }

    //
    // POST: /PostManager/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserProfile userprofile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(userprofile).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(userprofile);
    }

    //
    // GET: /PostManager/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        UserProfile userprofile = db.UserProfiles.Find(id);
        if (userprofile == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(userprofile);
    }

    //
    // POST: /PostManager/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        UserProfile userprofile = db.UserProfiles.Find(id);
        db.UserProfiles.Remove(userprofile);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
```

**3.edit the index page to contain the two views, one for adding and the second to retrieve , as below:**

```
        @using System.Linq;
    @model  workingOnAddPost.Entity.UserProfile
    @{

    };

    @*<p>*@

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/myScript.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/Styles/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@*<div class="Button addcontent">
      <button type="button" >
          <em class="icon-plus"></em>
      </button>
</div>*@
```

@

@

```
    @section featured {
        <section class="featured">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <hgroup class="title">
                    <h1>@*ViewBag.Title.*@</h1>
                    <h2>@*ViewBag.Message*@</h2>
                </hgroup>
                <p>
                    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit
                    <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
                    The page features <mark>videos, tutorials, and samples</mark> to help you get the most from ASP.NET MVC.
                    If you have any questions about ASP.NET MVC visit
                    <a href="http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx/1?MVC" title="ASP.NET MVC Forum">our forums</a>.
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
    }

    <div class="Button addcontent">
        <button type="button">
            <em class="icon-plus"></em>
        </button>
    </div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


            <div class="modal-addcontent">
                <div class="modal">
                    <div class="standardForm">
                        <h1>
                            Add new content
                        </h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <h3>
                                    <label>
                                        Id=
                                    </label>
                                </h3>
                                <div class="editor-field">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserId)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId)
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h3>
                                    <label>
                                        Name:
                                    </label>
                                </h3>
                                <div class="editor-field">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h3>
                                    <label>
                                        Description
                                    </label>
                                </h3>

                                <div class="content">
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PostContent)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostContent)
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h3>
                                    <label>
                                        Image
                                    </label>
                                </h3>
                                <div>
                                    <input id="upload" type="file" />
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="formFooter">
                            <div class="FooterButtons">
                                <button class="Button btn close-modalpopup" type="button">
                                    <span class="buttonText">
                                        Cancel
                                    </span>
                                </button>
                                <p>
                                    <button class="Button primary btn" type="submit" value="Create">
                                        <span class="buttonText">
                                            Create
                                        </span>
                                    </button>

                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            }
<h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
<ol class="round">
    <li class="one">
        <h5>Getting Started</h5>
        ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
        enables a clean separation of concerns and that gives you full control over markup
        for enjoyable, agile development. ASP.NET MVC includes many features that enable
        fast, TDD-friendly development for creating sophisticated applications that use
        the latest web standards.
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245151">Learn more…</a>
    </li>

    <li class="two">
        <h5>Add NuGet packages and jump-start your coding</h5>
        NuGet makes it easy to install and update free libraries and tools.
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245153">Learn more…</a>
    </li>

    <li class="three">
        <h5>Find Web Hosting</h5>
        You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features
        and price for your applications.
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245157">Learn more…</a>
    </li>
</ol>
@*<table>*@
@foreach (var item in Model.UserProfilesCollection)
{

    <div id="main">
        <div id="main-inner">
            <div id="container" class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer", "itemSelector": ".item"}'>
                <div class="grid-sizer">
                <div class="item open-modal">
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(Modelitem => item.PostContent)
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
        @* </table>*@
```

Comment: @AkramAlshameeri That not the same but yes it matches my needs. Thanks so much. and the code that you provided is enough u don't need to upload a file you should remove it.

Answer (score 3):

In your post action, you're not setting a value for `MovieCollection` on your view model. This information doesn't survive the request, and you're not even accepting the full view model from the post, if it did. As a result, you simply need to repopulate the list in your post action before returning the view.

Comment: i guess i did in get action!! 'MovieCollection = db.Movies.ToList()' doesn't work?

Comment: That works for your *get action*. You need the same thing in your *post action*.

Comment: Do you mean adding 'MovieCollection = db.Movies.ToList()' in the same variable of my post action. Like this 'var model = new MovieViewModel() { MovieCollection = db.Movies.ToList(), Movie = movie, }; ' ? doesn't work.
Please provide me answer with more details i'm beginner .